# Alertar texto só de um elemento específico

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho esse código :

```html
<div id="div">
  This is some text.<br/>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
<script>
  alert(document.getElementById("div").innerText);
</script>
```

e quando eu peço para alertar o texto de `#div`, ele alerta o texto do botão também.

Eu sei que isso não é um bug e que já era para acontecer isso, mas tem um método para alertar somente o texto do `#div` sem incluir o texto do botão?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tens de usar `node`(s), não podes ir por Elementos pois esse texto está dentro do elemento ao mesmo nível do `button`. Mas usando `node` já consegues. Por exemplo o `.firstChild`  dá-te o primeiro `node` e o `.textContent` o conteúdo.

```html
<div id="div">
  This is some text.<br/>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
<script>
  alert(document.getElementById("div").firstChild.textContent);
</script>
```